# How to sync Gmail IMAP subfolders for Outlook 2013?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, gmail-imap, microsoft-outlook-2013

I currently have my Gmail account synced with Outlook 2013 using IMAP, since the Google Apps Sync utility isn't compatible with Outlook 2013 yet. However, I've encountered a problem where my inbox's subfolders aren't being retrieved from the server.

Is there a way to have Outlook retrieve the inbox's subfolders as well?

Comment: If by "retrieve" you mean "push", then it's (more or less) expected: IMAP IDLE monitors only a single folder. Just as a side note.

Answer (score 0):

view the folders list and subscribe to the ones you want

Don't have an Outlook system handy to view but from memory you would right click on the imap root folder (left side of the Outlook window for the folder list is displayed) and select properties(?), should bring up a dialog box to allow downloading the folder list and then subscribe to the ones you want. I'm sure Outlook help search with "imap subscribe" can help with your specific version.

Comment: Care to expand on this suggestion?  Perhaps add some punctuation? :)

Comment: Don't have an Outlook system handy to view but from memory you would right click on the imap root folder (left side of the Outlook window for the folder list is displayed) and select properties(?), should bring up a dialog box to allow downloading the folder list and then subscribe to the ones you want. I'm sure Outlook help search with "imap subscribe" can help with your specific version.

Comment: You should edit that info into your answer.  As-is it's been flagged for low-quality and content, and if not expanded upon may be deleted.

Comment: into question or into answer?

Comment: Sorry 'bout that, edit your _answer_. (I fixed my comment after you saw it :) )

Comment: too much hand-holding isn't always the best - sometimes nudging the user towards the solution provides the best learning experiance

Comment: I've added the subfolder and all the subfolders within it that I want to get synced and they're currently showing under the 'Subscribed' tab, but no e-mails seem to be showing, despite there being e-mails on the Gmail account for those subfolders.

Comment: have you expanded the gmail folder tree in the left hand panel?

Comment: Yes, the folder tree has been expanded and all subfolders have been added within the IMAP folder settings to be subscribed to.

Comment: you can see the subscribed folders in the left hand panel but when you open them none of the emails they contain (that you see in the web interface) show up?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: possibly view settings?

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officeitpro/thread/cd4c54cf-00f9-4ba9-b558-0fe69513f909/) has some possible answers. Scroll through it. The one finally working for me was disabling **all** add-ins & now it is syncing.

My folders themselves synced before, but they were empty. Now the emails are finally coming over.

Also, if you're still not having success, check out [this site](http://www.slipstick.com/featured/what-you-need-to-know-about-outlook-2013/). There seems to be some irreparable compatibility issues because Gmail uses an older version of EAS.

Answer (score 0):

just had the same problem with another IMAP mail provider:
seems an Outlook Flaw.

Solution was to first create folder online or with other IMAP Client than Outlook.
This Folder won't appear in Outlooks's Folder tree view, BUT in IMAP Query.

Now simply creaty than folder with same name in the same location inside Outlook.
Be aware of ***case sensititity***!

now it will sync as it should.

Answer (score 0):

It is 2020 and this issue still exists using Outlook 2016. What helped me today:

- Open tab "Send/Receive"
- Find and click "Define send/receive groups". This should open a new window.
- Double click the group you want your mail to collect. Opens another window.
- Choose your IMAP account on the left
- Find "receive messages"
- By default "Sync all subscribed folders" is selected. Choose "Define user-defined behavior below".
- Enable all folders you want to sync

Better do no check all. I have a hunch that this issue might be related to a limited number of connections a client can establish to the IMAP server. This limited can be changed by the server. Outlook probably uses one connection per folder. So when IMAP syncing worked for you but then stopped working -- it may be due to new IMAP folders that you added.

Hence, to solve the problem you can also try to remove some IMAP folders that you do not need.